# Send POST data as hidden input name value array

Tags: javascript, jquery, gridview, yii2

I am using yii2 Activeform and a gridview

There are 2 fields `message` and `file` on a form and `submit` button

And `gridview` on the same page..

So when the user checks any user from checkbox column and type the `message` than `message` should be sent to all selected users

Here is what I have done so far

```
<div class="row">
    <p>
        <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options'=>['enctype'=>'multipart/form-data','id' => 'message-form']]); ?>

    <div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'message')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-3 col-lg-3">
        <?= $form->field($model, 'file')->fileInput() ?>
        <?= $form->field($model, 'keys[]')->hiddenInput()->label(false); ?>

        <div class="form-group">
            <?= Html::submitButton('Send',['class' => 'btn btn-danger','data-placement'=>'right','id'=>'sendMessage']) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
    </p>
</div>
```

Above is the form.. Now I can get the `keys` variable in action but the format of that array is something like this

```
Keys{
  0="1,5,7,6,8"
}
```

Where as I want that format to be like this

```
Keys{
  0="1",
  1="2",
  2="5",
  3="7",
}
```

So how can I send data to the controller in that format along with `message` and `file`

At the moment I am sending data through hidden output field but it's not sending data in my desired format.
I know this can be done using javascript but not sure how to do that??

Here is a javaquery I am using

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
    var keys = $("#checkin-table").yiiGridView("getSelectedRows");
    sendKeys.val(keys);
    if(keys.length > 0){
        sendMessage.removeClass("disabled");
    }
    else if(keys.length==0){
        sendMessage.addClass("disabled");
    }
});
```

Comment: If you want to convert above array use `explode()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

Comment: @insaneSkulll i thought of that and i can do that but `explode()` needs parameter as string and i need to first convert it to string and than pass it so i am thinking of some other alternative.. may be using `javascript`

Comment: you can use `settype()` function to convert your array into integer array.

Comment: @insaneSkulll ok let me try that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding the hidden field in your form only render one time because you are using `[]` you only get index `0` in your `$keys` variable with all the values, what you need `$keys = array(1,3,4,5)` so you need to render keys field multiple time eg:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'keys[]')->hiddenInput(['value' => 1])->label(false); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'keys[]')->hiddenInput(['value' => 2])->label(false); ?>
```

If you don't need this you can just do in your current scenario:

```
$keys = Yii::$app->request->post('keys');
$keys = explode(",",$keys[0]);
```

Comment: you are right but i have already written a javascript which sends all checked columns as an array on submission